# I found Solutions related to MY-SQL. my requirement is for oracle.what should i write in the POJO class to get the below schema structure by hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
create table users (
    username varchar(50) not null primary key,
    password varchar(120) not null,
    enabled number (1,0) not null
);
```

Mainly I need to declare **enabled number (1,0) not null** in Hibernate.

Comment: if anyone knows please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody helped me with the above question but no issues I myself found the answer after a lot many thing and searches.

There are many solutions already uploaded on stack overflow but they respected MY-SQL.
But I wanted it for Oracle. Now I have the Solution.

Please find it below. Maybe someone needs it like me.

Kindly **Note:** Oracle doesn't support TINYINT as well as BOOLEAN.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserRegistration {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "NUMBER(1)")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    private boolean enabled;
}
```